# Can you run MVC5 apps on a server running .Net 4.03 or below?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I have an app that need to be deployed to a server and as you can see from the screenshot, it has two older versions of the .Net framework running. I was under the impression MVC5 needs .Net 4.5 or above, for which I would need to inform my server admin of the minimum .Net requirement. This server is mostly running VB6 legacy apps.

[image: .Net frameworks on server:]

Comment: Short answer...yes

Comment: @jumpingcode Yes you can set MVC5 apps to target 4.03 framework or yes 4.5 is the minimum framework for MVC5 apps?